Expo React Native WebSocket Connection Fails in Production Build
Description:
While developing a React Native application with Expo, I've encountered an issue with WebSocket connections. The connections work fine in the simulator and Expo Go, but they fail after building the app using Expo for physical devices through Testflight or Google Play.
Environment & Dependencies:

Expo SDK Version: 51.0.8

React Native Version: 0.74.1

socket.io-client Version: 4.7.5

Backend Technology: NestJS 10.0.0 + Socket.IO 4.7.5

Build Tool: Expo build (eas)

Checked if the SSL certificate is trusted and not self-signed. The result is an A rating.

Adjusted the Nginx reverse proxy to confirm successful connection via a PC browser.

Confirmed that the WebSocket server address is consistent across all environments, being a public network server address.

Using the HTTPS protocol with an SSL certificate, the server-side NestJS has CORS configured to *.

Tested in Expo Go on iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone Xs Max, and Redmi K30i, which worked normally, but after building and installing through TestFlight and Google Play, the connection could not be established.


Expected Behavior:
WebSocket connections should be consistent across all environments, including the production build.
Actual Behavior:
WebSocket connections cannot be established in the production build.

I'm having the same issue, this is with a program in which websocket used to work in production.
